# Conditional formatting for contains certain text from a range of values

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

How do you do conditional formatting to find out if range 2 contains the text value from  range 1? For example check for Apple in red apple should highlight it.
I need to compare A3:A6 with C3:C7. The end result should be C3, C4 and C5 highlighted.

```
A   B            C
1 Range1       Range2
==========================
3 Apple        Red Apple
4 Orange       Green Apple
5 Pear         Orange
6 Watermelon   Banana
7              Kiwi
```

I tried this formula but it only check B3 against Range2 and skips B4 to B6.

```
=FIND($B$3:$B$6,C3)>0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible and I had fun working on this problem but I really wish you had done some work as well - seeing your own effort would have been just as rewarding as solving the problem by myself.

[image]

The formula to be used with conditional formatting is:
`=NOT(ISERROR(AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($A$1:$A$4)/SEARCH($A$1:$A$4,B1), 1)))=TRUE`

It obviously works as a normal, non-array formula too:

[image]

Comment: But we can't use array formula in conditional formatting?

Comment: It's impossible to use one that requires Control-Shift-Enter to work, but it's possible to use one that uses the AGGREGATE function as per my solution.  Phew.  That was fun to solve.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The conditional formatting formula looks quite complicated.